# SWFObject 2.2 static publishing method and click-to-activate mechanisms in legacy IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6, swfobject

As you know in legacy (and unpatched) Internet Explorer, you have to click on active content (like Flash) to start it. I know Microsoft added the click-to-activate "feature" then removed it a couple of years after but I'm still stuck with customers with this "feature" still there.

I would like to use SWFObject 2.2 (latest) to embed Flash on my site. The static publishing method is the one I would like to use (for the rare case where JavaScript is OFF), but would also like to get rid of the click-to-activate feature when present (this seem to be only available with the dynamic publishing method).

Is what I want possible with SWFObject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that it's possible by combining static and dynamic publishing methods.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194959/whats-the-ultimate-way-to-embed-flash-swf-files-to-html-and-xhtml-documents) for the follow-up.