# What's the ultimate way to embed Flash (swf) files to HTML (and XHTML) documents?

Tags: javascript, flash, swfobject

Like most people I use SWFObject to embed Flash (swf) files to my Web projects.

As you know [SWFObject offers 2 ways to embed Flash](https://helpx.adobe.com/air/archived-docs-download.html): Static publishing and Dynamic publishing.

**Static publishing** uses regular markup to embed the file to the document and also do checks with JavaScript that you can't make with regular markup alone. This is good as if you have customers that can't have JavaScript turned on (search engines, some portable devices...), the file will still show up (if they have the correct Flash plug-in installed). But if you have people on legacy/unpatched Internet Explorer ([between April 2006 and April 2008](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ie/ie-automatic-component-activation-changes-to-ie-activex-update)) they will have the dreaded "click to activate" to interact with the Flash.

**Dynamic publishing** uses JavaScript to embed the Flash. This will get rid of the "click to activate" feature on old IE but if JavaScript is off the Flash will not be there at all.

Both methods have its advantages and inconvenients. In an utopic world we would all use the dynamic publishing method, but we (or at least some of us like me) are stuck with customers using really old systems with IE 6 (they would like to upgrade but they can't because of badly designed software that would cost 10K+$ to upgrade). I need to support legacy IE and want to get rid of the "click to activate" feature while supporting people with JavaScript off.

What about combining static **and** dynamic publishing methods? What about something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>SWFObject 2 static+dynamic publishing example page</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        swfobject.embedSWF("test.swf", "myContent", "300", "120", "9.0.0", "expressInstall.swf");
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="myContent">
            <object id="myId" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="300" height="120">
                <param name="movie" value="test.swf" />
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="test.swf" width="300" height="120">
                <!--<![endif]-->
                <div>
                    <h1>Alternative content</h1>
                    <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" /></a></p>
                </div>
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                </object>
                <!--<![endif]-->
            </object>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I showed that to an integrator and he told me I should use `<object>` and `<embed>` tags...

What would be the ultimate way to embed Flash to Web projects? A solution that:

- Will work with JavaScript off (Flash embedded in alternate content)
- Will pass the W3C validator
- Will remove the "click to activate" on legacy/unpatched IE
- Will use the Flash detection/auto-install of SWFObject

**EDIT:** Added bounty. Please, I don't want to see answers like "don't bother no one have JavaScript off nowdays" or "if javascript is off most likely Flash will be off too".

---

**EDIT 2:** The answer I'm looking for is the best way to embed Flash statically (with regular HTML tags). Over that, I will add dynamic publishing. Something [like this](https://alistapart.com/article/flashsatay/) that will work in **all** major browsers since IE 6 and that will pass W3C validation.

---

Comment: *Static publishing uses*, not *Static publishing use*.
*Dynamic publishing uses*, not *Dynamic publishing will use* to maintain tense.

Comment: Fixed! I'm doing my best as English is not my main language :)

Comment: Is using `<script>`/`<noscript>` to include both approaches along the right lines?

Comment: If needed yes, but I don't see the use since you embed the Flash statically with regular tags and add over that script to add features. The noscript would be useless since the Flash is already there even without script (if you have the plug installed).

Comment: Surely the "best" way to do it would be the way Adobe recommends in that article? Specifically: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/swfobject_05.html

Comment: and where is <embed> tag?! in my opinion you can add <embed> for more compatibility

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"> </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            swfobject.embedSWF('test.swf', 'myFlash', '320', '240', '9.0.0', '/swfobject/expressInstall.swf', 0, 0, 0);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <object id="myFlash" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="320" height="240">
                <param name="movie" value="test.swf">
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="test.swf" width="320" height="240">
                <!--<![endif]-->
                    <p>Version ???</p>
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                </object>
                <!--<![endif]-->
            </object>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

- I combine the static **and** dynamic methods of [SWFObject](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/swfobject_05.html)
- The static part is using the [nested-objects method](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/flashembedcagematch/)

Comment: Thx, I like your approach. Additionally I use the CDN source: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script>

Answer (score 5):

```
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script> 
    <script>
    var flashVars = {};
    var params = {};
        params.allowScriptAccess = "always";
        params.allowFullScreen = false;
        params.bgcolor = "#1a1a1a";
        params.wmode = "opaque";

        var atts = {};
        atts.id = "my-swf";

    swfobject.embedSWF("my.swf", "my-swfobject", "100%", "100%", "10.1.0", "playerProductInstall.swf", flashVars, params, atts);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="my-swfobject">
        <!-- Any <object></object>, <embed></embed>, and everything else here will be rendered for users without JavaScript. If JavaScript is on, SWFObject will destroy div#my-swfobject and replace it with object#my-swf. -->
    </div>
</body>
```

Let me know if this is what you're looking for. I can elaborate more if needed. You might also consider suggesting that your IE6 slaves install Google Chrome Frame: http://code.google.com/chrome/chromeframe/

Comment: No it's not what I'm looking for (it's dynamic only). I'm looking for the best way to embed Flash statically (with regular tags). I will add over that dynamic publishing. Chrome Frame can solve a lot of things, but I find that running a browser in a browser is somewhat fuzzy :) I would rather tell them to install Chrome and run it from there

Comment: It's not dynamic only, you're supposed to put the html code for the static plug-in inside `<div id="my-swfobject"></div>`. If the user has javascript enabled SWFObject will replace that code with generated code, otherwise the static code inside the div will run.

Comment: Yes I know but I'm looking for the best static way to do it (see Edit 2).

Comment: Alex -- the best static way happens to be the only static way. See an implementation example here: http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/415/tn_4150.html

The code I posted is dynamic with a place for a static fallback. This is the preferred method because it gracefully degrades for those with JavaScript disabled. Put your static code inside div#my-swfobject and you will find that ANYTHING you place there is rendered as if SWFObject was never loaded (because it wasn't).

Comment: AlexV, this solution is a good one that meets your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for shorting me on the bounty! Maybe you can explain in more detail why my solution doesn't meet your needs. Are the tags invalid HTML? Does it not work in a particular browser?

Comment: The solution you've posted is the same (but less complete) than the exact one in my OP...

Answer (score 1):

What I've done in the past is statically put my flash content in a  div (using both object and embed tags), and then have SWFObject overwrite the contents of that div when it loads.  This will be as close to what you want to do as you can get.

Comment: This is what I want to do, but I'm looking for the best (static) way to embed Flash...

Answer (score 0):

Go with dynamic publishing. If the user has javascript turned off, give up. They won't want Flash to run either.

Comment: Yeah but AFAIK with dynamic publishing your Flash content is not indexed by (at least some) search engines.

In my case I have customers stuck with old IE. Some others not, I would like to take the best of all worlds (even if it's meaning more work for me).

Comment: Yes I did want Flash to run when I used NoScript in my old Firefox profile. What I didn't want was annoying ads and bad usage of Flash.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way to get your clients to install another browser (like Firefox) alongside their legacy one, and use IE6 for the legacy app and FF for yours?

Comment: Yes that's a solution which can be applied with some pain (deployment and training). But I'm not asking how to avoid this problem. I truly want to know the ultimate way to embed Flash (It's more curiosity than real use).

Comment: There is no "ultimate" way to embed Flash. Just use whatever works best for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a cue from sites such as YouTube that allow embedding of Flash. Not sure if this will work for non "movie" types.

From YouTube:

```
<object width="[width]" height="[height]">
<param name="movie" value="[Path to SWF]"></param>
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
<embed src="[Path to SWF]" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="[width]" height="[height]"></embed>
</object>
```

Answer (score 0):

the only way i see, is doing something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        <object width="160" height="112" data="movie.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
            <param name="movie" value="movie.swf" />
        </object>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

there is no better option i think. this will work in IE , Mozilla and Webkit browsers and is xhtml valid. but there is no flash installer and no replacement.